# replit django change url

Tags: python, rfc

I am Using the new functionality released by repl.it that allows you to create Django projects on their platform. I tried to make a project but it is giving me an error that says that the url is not good. I tried with a different account and it seems that my username was the problem (it has an underscore in it). Is there a way to manually set the url? Here is the error

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'fabulousflippantelement--alek_westover.repl.co'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is on us - it's because there's an underscore in your username.  As a temporary fix, you can change your username here: https://repl.it/account/change_username

We'll work on getting a fix out to convert underscores in URLs.  Thanks for the heads up!